# Add forms dynamically in admin pages?

Tags: custom-field, ajax, metabox

I'm developing a WP plugin and I need that each time the user press a button in the metaboxes field, the form appears bellow the first one, so the user can add as many as they need WITHOUT RELOAD THE PAGE. I've been trying a lot for at least 3-4 days with no success :(

My metabox is:

[image: Metabox fields]

My code in metaboxes.php is the following:

```php
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

function cotizador_agregar_metaboxes()
{
    add_meta_box('cotizador_meta_box', 'Características del Vehiculo', 'cotizador_metaboxes', 'vehiculos', 'normal', 'high', null);
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'cotizador_agregar_metaboxes');


function cotizador_metaboxes($post)
{
    cotizador_bootstrap();
    wp_nonce_field(basename(__FILE__), 'cotizador_nonce');
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $query_result = cotizador_query_select($post_id);

    // echo "<pre>";
    //    var_dump(cotizador_add_model($post));
    // echo "</pre>";
?>
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <h2>Shortcode:</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
            <code class="mr-5">[cotizador id="<?php echo $post_id ?>"]</code>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="true" id="btn_add_model" value="Agregar Modelo" onclick="add_model();" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <form>
        <?php
        cotizador_add_model($post);
        ?>
    </form>
<?php
}

function cotizador_guardar_metaboxes($post_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = 'wp_cotiza_vehicles_list';

    if (!isset($_POST['cotizador_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['cotizador_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_model'])) {
        $car_model = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_model']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_price'])) {
        $car_price = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_price']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_brand'])) {
        $car_brand = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_brand']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_year'])) {
        $car_year = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_year']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_type'])) {
        $car_type = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_type']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_basefee'])) {
        $car_basefee = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_basefee']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_basemodel'])) {
        $car_basemodel = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_basemodel']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_rcusa'])) {
        $car_rcusa = sanitize_text_field($_POST['car_rcusa']);
    }
    if (isset($_POST['car_bono'])) {
        $car_bono = 1;
    } else {
        $car_bono = 0;
    }

    /* sending data to custom table */
    if (cotizador_query_select($post_id) == null) {
        $wpdb->insert($table_name, array(
            'post_id' => $post_id,
            'car_model' => $car_model,
            'car_price' => $car_price,
            'car_brand' => $car_brand,
            'car_year' => $car_year,
            'car_type' => $car_type,
            'car_basefee' => $car_basefee,
            'car_basemodel' => $car_basemodel,
            'car_rcusa' => $car_rcusa,
            'car_bono' => $car_bono,
        ));
    } else {
        $wpdb->update($table_name, array(
            'car_model' => $car_model,
            'car_price' => $car_price,
            'car_brand' => $car_brand,
            'car_year' => $car_year,
            'car_type' => $car_type,
            'car_basefee' => $car_basefee,
            'car_basemodel' => $car_basemodel,
            'car_rcusa' => $car_rcusa,
            'car_bono' => $car_bono,
        ), array('post_id' => $post_id));
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'cotizador_guardar_metaboxes', 10, 3);
?>
```

I Created a metabox_ajax.php file where the form is inside a function called in "metabox.php", I did this thinking that "when button is pressed, send a counter in order to add the counter in the next forms to be able to add all of them into db"

metabox_ajax.php

```php
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

function cotizador_add_model($post)
{
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    $query_result = cotizador_query_select($post_id);
    $i = $_POST['counter'];
?>
    <br class="mb-5">
    <table id="model-1" class="mb-5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_model">Modelo:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input value="<?php echo esc_attr($query_result['car_model']); ?>" type='text' placeholder='Modelo' id="vehicle_model" name="car_model" class="regular-text">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="mt-5">
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_price">Precio:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input value="<?php echo esc_attr($query_result['car_price']); ?>" type='number' step='0.01' placeholder='0000.00' id="vehicle_price" name="car_price" class="regular-text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_brand">Marca:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <?php $brand = esc_html($query_result['car_brand']); ?>
                    <select id="vehicle_brand" name="car_brand" class="post-box">
                        <option value="" selected hidden>Selecciona una marca</option>
                        <option <?php selected($brand, 'Chrysler'); ?> value="Chrysler">Chrysler</option>
                        <option <?php selected($brand, 'RAM'); ?> value="RAM">RAM</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_year">Año:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <?php $year = esc_html($query_result['car_year']); ?>
                    <select id="vehicle_year" name="car_year" class="post-box">
                        <option value="" selected hidden>Selecciona un año</option>
                        <option <?php selected($year, 2020); ?> value="2020">2020</option>
                        <option <?php selected($year, 2019); ?> value="2019">2019</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_type">Tipo:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <?php $type = esc_html($query_result['car_type']); ?>
                    <select id="vehicle_type" name="car_type" class="post-box">
                        <option value="" selected hidden>Tipo de vehículo</option>
                        <option <?php selected($type, 'Auto'); ?> value="Auto">Auto</option>
                        <option <?php selected($type, 'PickUp'); ?> value="PickUp">PickUp</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_basefee">Constante cuota base:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input value="<?php echo esc_attr($query_result['car_basefee']); ?>" type='number' step='0.01' placeholder='0000.00' id="vehicle_basefee" name="car_basefee" class="regular-text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_basemodel">Porcentaje base:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input value="<?php echo esc_attr($query_result['car_basemodel']); ?>" type='number' step='0.000001' placeholder='0.000000' id="vehicle_basemodel" name="car_basemodel" class="regular-text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_rcusa">RC USA:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <input value="<?php echo esc_attr($query_result['car_rcusa']); ?>" type='number' step='0.01' placeholder='0000.00' id="vehicle_rcusa" name="car_rcusa" class="regular-text">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th class="row-title">
                    <label for="vehicle_bono">BONO:</label>
                </th>
                <td>
                    <?php if ($query_result['car_bono'] == 1) {
                        $checked = 'checked';
                    } else {
                        $checked = 'unchecked';
                    } ?>
                    <input <?php echo $checked ?> type='checkbox' id="vehicle_bono" name="car_bono" class="regular-text">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php
}
/* always add following actions in order to make ajax work */
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cotizador_from_ajax', 'cotizador_from_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_cotizador_from_ajax', 'cotizador_from_ajax');
/* following function to show up forms if button clicked */
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cotizador_add_model', 'cotizador_add_model');
add_action('wp_ajax_cotizador_add_model', 'cotizador_add_model');
```

I also created the script in order to use ajax in scripts.php file inside my plugin:

scripts.php

```php
<?php
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

function cotizador_bootstrap() 
{       
    // CSS
    wp_register_style('cotizador_bootstrap_css', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('cotizador_bootstrap_css');

    // JS
    wp_register_script('cotizador_bootstrap_jquery', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js');
    wp_register_script('cotizador_bootstrap_popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js');
    wp_register_script('cotizador_bootstrap_js', 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script('cotizador_bootstrap_jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('cotizador_bootstrap_popper');
    wp_enqueue_script('cotizador_bootstrap_js');
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cotizador_bootstrap');

/* adding scripts into admin panel */
function cotizador_metabox_scripts(){
    wp_register_script('metaboxes_js', plugins_url('../assets/js/metaboxes.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), 1.0, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('metaboxes_js');
    wp_localize_script('metaboxes_js', 'admin_url', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('any_value_here'),
    ));
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'cotizador_metabox_scripts');
```

as you can see at the end of this file i'm creating the ajax_url to use /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

And finally this is my js file:

```js
function add_model() {
    $('#btn_add_model').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let i = 1;
        /* creamos la conexion ajax, WP ya tiene esta funcionalidad por default */
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            action: 'cotizador_add_model',
            url: admin_url.ajax_url,
            data: {
                counter: i,
                nonce: admin_url.ajax_nonce
            },
            complete: function (response) {
                console.log(`I got this from server: ${response}`)
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        
    });
    return false;
};
```

And this is what I see in wp (also, when I press the button, the page reload):

[image]

Comment: have you tried doing it with javascript/jquery? if you are trying to catch the form submit then try to listen to `submit` event of the form element.

Comment: My suggestion would be to do tihs in simple PHP and HTML first before you try to bring it to Wordpress. Make the dynamic form do what you want in the simplest possible way, get it working, then build on that. To get more responses to this quesiton you need to really simplify it down to the one clear question and a specific piece of code that you are asking for help with.